# firebase retrieve user data swift

Tags: swift, firebase

I am having a couple of issues with firebase right at the moment and was wondering if anyone out there could help me out. Currently I have an app with many users who save data that they type in. All of these being numbers. The database is saving how I want it to save. it save by a key and within the key has the UID the Month the Year and the number that they are saving.

My Question is:
How do I retrieve the Data so that it only pulls out what the user saved? How do I make the database check for only data saved by the current user and then allow that to be retreived. I have set this up in rules where the user has to be authenticated to both read and right.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, I have read through all of the docs and tried a lot of there examples and I still can not figure it out.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I retrieve the Data so that it only pulls out what the user
>   saved?
>
> How do I make the database check for only data saved by the current
>   user and then allow that to be retreived.

These are slightly different questions but seem to ask the same thing.

Assuming from your question, a structure as follows

```
firebase_key_0
   user_id: uid_0
   month:   06
   number:  42
firebase_key_1
   user_id: uid_1
   month:   03
   number:  .14
```

then a basic firebase query to get the specific data; here's the code to get user uid_1's number:

```
ref.queryOrderedByChild("user_id").queryEqualToValue("uid_1")
     .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        if ( snapshot.value is NSNull ) {
            print("not found")
        } else {
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let n = child.value["number"] as! String
                print(n) //prints .14
            }
        }
})
```

There's some extra error checking included as well as being able to handle .Value returning multiple child nodes. For example, if uid_1 had multiple numbers stored, this will retrieve all of them and print each one.

The current user uid would be obtained from their authData.uid when the log in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... It does work. I do have another question based on this same theory. Could you pull based on two nodes. for instance could I pull the data the user saved and what month they saved it in the same style code to better sort the Data. Using your example "uid_1 in the month of 3 ""march"" had a value of .14... uid_0 in the month of 6 ""june"" had a value of 42"? Thansk again you are a huge help to me

Comment: nevermind I figured it out... Your help really set me on the right track... Thanks again I appreciate it.

Comment: @IcculusGreat! If it helped you, it may help others so don't forget to accept the answer!